# Laziness and tail recursion in Haskell, why is this crashing?

Tags: performance, optimization, haskell, lazy-evaluation, ghc

I have this fairly simple function to compute the mean of elements of a big list, using two accumulators to hold the sum so far and the count so far:

```
mean = go 0 0
    where
      go s l []     = s / fromIntegral l
      go s l (x:xs) = go (s+x) (l+1) xs

main = do
  putStrLn (show (mean [0..10000000]))
```

Now, in a strict language, this would be tail-recursive, and there would be no problem. However, as Haskell is lazy, my googling has led me to understand that (s+x) and (l+1) will be passed down the recursion as thunks. So this whole thing crashes and burns:

```
Stack space overflow: current size 8388608 bytes.
```

After further googling, I found `seq` and `$!`. Which it seems I don't understand because all my attempts at using them in this context proved futile, with error messages saying something about infinite types.

Finally I found `-XBangPatterns`, which solves it all by changing the recursive call:

```
go !s !l (x:xs) = go (s+x) (l+1) xs
```

But I'm not happy with this, as `-XBangPatterns` is currently an extension. I would like to know how to make the evaluation strict without the use of `-XBangPatterns`. (And maybe learn something too!)

Just so you understand my lack of understanding, here's what I tried (the only try that compiled, that is):

```
go s l (x:xs) = go (seq s (s+x)) (seq l (l+1)) xs
```

From what I could understand, seq should here force the evaluation of the s and l argument, thus avoiding the problem caused by thunks. But I still get a stack overflow.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

I've written extensively on this:

- [Real World Haskell, ch 24: controlling evaluation](http://book.realworldhaskell.org/read/profiling-and-optimization.html#id678431)
- [On recursion and strictness in Haskell](http://donsbot.wordpress.com/2008/06/04/haskell-as-fast-as-c-working-at-a-high-altitude-for-low-level-performance/)

Firstly, yes, if you want to require strict evaluation of the accumulators use `seq` and stay in Haskell 98:

```
mean = go 0 0
  where
    go s l []     = s / fromIntegral l
    go s l (x:xs) = s `seq` l `seq`
                      go (s+x) (l+1) xs

main = print $ mean [0..10000000]

*Main> main
5000000.0
```

Secondly: strictness analysis will kick in if you give some type annotations, and compile with -O2:

```
mean :: [Double] -> Double
mean = go 0 0
 where
  go :: Double -> Int -> [Double] -> Double
  go s l []     = s / fromIntegral l
  go s l (x:xs) = go (s+x) (l+1) xs

main = print $ mean [0..10000000]

$ ghc -O2 --make A.hs
[1 of 1] Compiling Main             ( A.hs, A.o )
Linking A ...

$ time ./A
5000000.0
./A  0.46s user 0.01s system 99% cpu 0.470 total
```

Because 'Double' is a wrapper over the strict atomic type Double#, with optimizations on, and a precise type, GHC runs strictness analysis and infers that the strict version will be ok.

```
import Data.Array.Vector

main = print (mean (enumFromToFracU 1 10000000))

data Pair = Pair !Int !Double

mean :: UArr Double -> Double   
mean xs = s / fromIntegral n
  where
    Pair n s       = foldlU k (Pair 0 0) xs
    k (Pair n s) x = Pair (n+1) (s+x)

$ ghc -O2 --make A.hs -funbox-strict-fields
[1 of 1] Compiling Main             ( A.hs, A.o )
Linking A ...

$ time ./A
5000000.5
./A  0.03s user 0.00s system 96% cpu 0.038 total
```

As described in the RWH chapter above.

Comment: Good stuff. Nice to know about the GHC optimizations, and thanks
for the link to the book, looks like a great resource. 

However, when I looked at sth's post it struck me that to me it
looks like the use of seq should break the tail-recursion. seq
must be evaluated after the recursive call to go has been
evaluated, so from my understanding of tail recursion, it should
no longer be tail recursive, and thus blow the stack. This of
course doesn't happen, so something is going on here. Does
Haskell treat seq specially? Or am I simply confused about
tail-recursion?

Comment: seq doesn't exist at runtime. It's just a hint to use a different evaluation strategy. You'll get entirely different code generated.

Think of it more like a {-# STRICT_WHNF #-} pragma

Answer (score 9):

The `seq` function forces evaluation of the first parameter once the function is called. When you pass `seq s (s+x)` as a parameter the `seq` function is *not* called immediately, because there is no need to evaluate the value of that parameter. You want the call to `seq` to be evaluated before the recursive call, so that that in turn can force its parameter to be evaluated.

Usually this is done link this:

```
 go s l (x:xs) = s `seq` l `seq` go (s+x) (l+1) xs
```

This is a syntactic variation of `seq s (seq l (go (s+x) (l+1) xs))`. Here the calls to `seq` are the outermost function calls in the expression. Because of Haskell's laziness this causes them to be evaluated first: `seq` is called with the still unevaluated parameters `s` and `seq l (go (s+x) (l+1) xs)`, evaluating the parameters is deferred to the point where somebody actually tries to access their values.

Now `seq` can force its first parameter to be evaluated before returning the rest of the expression. Then the next step in the evaluation would be the second `seq`. If the calls to `seq` are buried somewhere in some parameter they might not be executed for a long time, defeating their purpose.

With the changed positions of the `seq`s the program executes fine, without using excessive amounts of memory.

Another solution to the problem would be to simply enable optimizations in GHC when the program is compiled (`-O` or `-O2`). The optimizer recognizes the dispensable laziness and produces code that doesn't allocate unnecessary memory.

Comment: In the absence of bang patterns, I like this way because it separates the forcing from the recursive call allowing it to be state in a clearer way.

Answer (score 6):

You are right in your understanding that `seq s (s+x)` forces the evaluation of `s`. But it doesn't force `s+x`, therefore you're still building up thunks.

By using `$!` you can force the evaluation of the addition (two times, for both arguments). This achieves the same effect as using the bang patterns:

```
mean = go 0 0
 where
    go s l []     = s / fromIntegral l
    go s l (x:xs) = ((go $! s+x) $! l+1) xs
```

---

The use of the `$!` function will translate the `go $! (s+x)` to the equivalent of:

```
let y = s+x 
in seq y (go y)
```

Thus `y` is first forced into *weak head normal form*, which means that the outermost function is applied. In the case of `y`, the outermost function is `+`, thus `y` is fully evaluated to a number before being passed to `go`.

---

Oh, and you probably got the infinite type error message because you didn't have the parenthesis in the right place. I got the same error when I first wrote your program down :-)

Because the `$!` operator is right associative, without parenthesis `go $! (s+x) $! (l+1)` means the same as: `go $! ((s+x) $! (l+1))`, which is obviously wrong.