# Computing the mean of a list efficiently in Haskell

Tags: performance, list, haskell

I've designed a function to compute the mean of a list. Although it works fine, but I think it may not be the best solution due to it takes two functions rather than one. Is it possible to do this job done with only one recursive function ?

```
calcMeanList (x:xs) = doCalcMeanList (x:xs) 0 0

doCalcMeanList (x:xs) sum length =  doCalcMeanList xs (sum+x) (length+1)
doCalcMeanList [] sum length = sum/length
```

Comment: It's good to keep in mind that any solution to this problem that amounts to simple division will produce NaN for the empty list. Not necessarily a problem, just something I thought was worth noting.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Laziness and tail recursion in Haskell, why is this crashing?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1618838/laziness-and-tail-recursion-in-haskell-why-is-this-crashing)

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1618838/laziness-and-tail-recursion-in-haskell-why-is-this-crashing/1618864#1618864

Comment: Sorry for committed a duplicated question. I will search more carefully next time.

Comment: @snowmantw: You couldn't have known, there's nothing in that question's title that suggests it's a question about calculating mean. @Don Stewart: I don't think it's a dupe. The code's very similar, but the questions about the code are quite different.

Comment: BTW, `sum` and `length` both are functions from Prelude, so you might want to use other variable names to avoid confusion.

Answer (score 11):

Your solution is good, using two functions is not worse than one. Still, you might put the tail recursive function in a `where` clause.

But if you want to do it in one line:

```
calcMeanList = uncurry (/) . foldr (\e (s,c) -> (e+s,c+1)) (0,0)
```

Comment: why foldr and not foldl? seems a much better fit to me.

Comment: foldl, foldl' or foldr can be used here as you must traverse the entire list anyway (it was the one I picked)... I think if the performance matters foldl' may be used here

Answer (score 10):

About the best you can do is [this version](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1618838/laziness-and-tail-recursion-in-haskell-why-is-this-crashing/1618864#1618864):

```
import qualified Data.Vector.Unboxed as U

data Pair = Pair {-# UNPACK #-}!Int {-# UNPACK #-}!Double

mean :: U.Vector Double -> Double
mean xs = s / fromIntegral n
  where
    Pair n s       = U.foldl' k (Pair 0 0) xs
    k (Pair n s) x = Pair (n+1) (s+x)

main = print (mean $ U.enumFromN 1 (10^7))
```

It fuses to an optimal loop in Core (the best Haskell you could write):

```
main_$s$wfoldlM'_loop :: Int#
                              -> Double#
                              -> Double#
                              -> Int#
                              -> (# Int#, Double# #)    
main_$s$wfoldlM'_loop =
  \ (sc_s1nH :: Int#)
    (sc1_s1nI :: Double#)
    (sc2_s1nJ :: Double#)
    (sc3_s1nK :: Int#) ->
    case ># sc_s1nH 0 of _ {
      False -> (# sc3_s1nK, sc2_s1nJ #);
      True ->
        main_$s$wfoldlM'_loop
          (-# sc_s1nH 1)
          (+## sc1_s1nI 1.0)
          (+## sc2_s1nJ sc1_s1nI)
          (+# sc3_s1nK 1)
    }
```

And the following assembly:

```
Main_mainzuzdszdwfoldlMzqzuloop_info:
.Lc1pN:
        testq %r14,%r14
        jg .Lc1pQ
        movq %rsi,%rbx
        movsd %xmm6,%xmm5
        jmp *(%rbp)
.Lc1pQ:
        leaq 1(%rsi),%rax
        movsd %xmm6,%xmm0
        addsd %xmm5,%xmm0
        movsd %xmm5,%xmm7
        addsd .Ln1pS(%rip),%xmm7
        decq %r14
        movsd %xmm7,%xmm5
        movsd %xmm0,%xmm6
        movq %rax,%rsi
        jmp Main_mainzuzdszdwfoldlMzqzuloop_info
```

Based on Data.Vector. For example,

```
$ ghc -Odph --make A.hs -fforce-recomp
[1 of 1] Compiling Main             ( A.hs, A.o )
Linking A ...
$ time ./A
5000000.5
./A  0.04s user 0.00s system 93% cpu 0.046 total
```

See the efficient implementations in [the statistics package](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/statistics).

Answer (score 5):

When I saw your question, I immediately thought "you want a [fold](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fold_%28higher-order_function%29) there!"

And sure enough, [a similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2376981/haskell-types-frustrating-a-simple-average-function) has been asked before on StackOverflow, and [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2376981/haskell-types-frustrating-a-simple-average-function/2380437#2380437) has a very performant solution, which you can test in an interactive environment like GHCi:

```
import Data.List

let avg l = let (t,n) = foldl' (\(b,c) a -> (a+b,c+1)) (0,0) l 
            in realToFrac(t)/realToFrac(n)

avg ([1,2,3,4]::[Int])
2.5
avg ([1,2,3,4]::[Double])
2.5
```

Answer (score 3):

While I am not sure whether or not it would be 'best' to write it in one function, it can be done as follows:

If you know the length (lets call it 'n' here)  in advance its easy -  you can calculate how much each value 'adds' to the average; that is going to be value/length.  Since `avg(x1, x2, x3) = sum(x1, x2, x3)/length = (x1 + x2 + x3)/3  =  x1/3 + x2/3 + x2/3`

If you don't know the length in advance, its a little trickier:

lets say we use the list `{x1,x2,x3}`  without knowing its n=3.

first iteration would just be x1 (since we assume its only n=1)
second iteration would add `x2/2`  and divide the existing average by 2 so now we have `x1/2 + x2/2`

after the third iteration we have n=3 and  we would want to have `x1/3 +x2/3 + x3/3`  but we have `x1/2 + x2/2`

so we would need to multiply by `(n-1)` and divide by `n` to get `x1/3 + x2/3`   and to that we just add the current value (x3) divided by n to end up with `x1/3 + x2/3 + x3/3`

Generally:

given an average (arithmetic mean - avg) for n-1 items, if you want to add one item(newval) to the average your equation will be:

`avg*(n-1)/n + newval/n`. The equation can be proven mathematically using induction.

Hope this helps.

*note this solution is less efficient than simply summing the variables and dividing by the total length as you do in your example.

Answer (score 3):

For those who are curious to know what glowcoder's and Assaf's approach would look like in Haskell, here's one translation:

```
avg [] = 0
avg x@(t:ts) = let xlen = toRational $ length x
                   tslen = toRational $ length ts
                   prevAvg = avg ts
               in (toRational t) / xlen + prevAvg * tslen / xlen
```

This way ensures that each step has the "average so far" correctly calculated, but does so at the cost of a whole bunch of redundant multiplying/dividing by lengths, and very inefficient calculations of length at each step. No seasoned Haskeller would write it this way.

An only slightly better way is:

```
avg2 [] = 0
avg2 x = fst $ avg_ x
    where 
      avg_ [] = (toRational 0, toRational 0)
      avg_ (t:ts) = let
           (prevAvg, prevLen) = avg_ ts
           curLen = prevLen + 1
           curAvg = (toRational t) / curLen + prevAvg * prevLen / curLen
        in (curAvg, curLen)
```

This avoids repeated length calculation. But it requires a helper function, which is precisely what the original poster is trying to avoid. And it still requires a whole bunch of canceling out of length terms.

To avoid the cancelling out of lengths, we can just build up the sum and length and divide at the end:

```
avg3 [] = 0
avg3 x = (toRational total) / (toRational len)
    where 
      (total, len) = avg_ x
      avg_ [] = (0, 0)
      avg_ (t:ts) = let 
          (prevSum, prevLen) = avg_ ts
       in (prevSum + t, prevLen + 1)
```

And this can be much more succinctly written as a foldr:

```
avg4 [] = 0
avg4 x = (toRational total) / (toRational len)
    where
      (total, len) = foldr avg_ (0,0) x
      avg_ t (prevSum, prevLen) = (prevSum + t, prevLen + 1)
```

which can be further simplified as per the posts above.

Fold really is the way to go here.

Answer (score 1):

To follow up on Don's 2010 reply, on GHC 8.0.2 we can do much better. First let's try his version.

```
module Main (main) where

import System.CPUTime.Rdtsc (rdtsc)
import Text.Printf (printf)
import qualified Data.Vector.Unboxed as U

data Pair = Pair {-# UNPACK #-}!Int {-# UNPACK #-}!Double

mean' :: U.Vector Double -> Double
mean' xs = s / fromIntegral n
  where
    Pair n s       = U.foldl' k (Pair 0 0) xs
    k (Pair n s) x = Pair (n+1) (s+x)

main :: IO ()
main = do
  s <- rdtsc
  let r = mean' (U.enumFromN 1 30000000)
  e <- seq r rdtsc
  print (e - s, r)
```

This gives us

```
[nix-shell:/tmp]$ ghc -fforce-recomp -O2 MeanD.hs -o MeanD && ./MeanD +RTS -s
[1 of 1] Compiling Main             ( MeanD.hs, MeanD.o )
Linking MeanD ...
(372877482,1.50000005e7)
     240,104,176 bytes allocated in the heap
           6,832 bytes copied during GC
          44,384 bytes maximum residency (1 sample(s))
          25,248 bytes maximum slop
             230 MB total memory in use (0 MB lost due to fragmentation)

                                     Tot time (elapsed)  Avg pause  Max pause
  Gen  0         1 colls,     0 par    0.000s   0.000s     0.0000s    0.0000s
  Gen  1         1 colls,     0 par    0.006s   0.006s     0.0062s    0.0062s

  INIT    time    0.000s  (  0.000s elapsed)
  MUT     time    0.087s  (  0.087s elapsed)
  GC      time    0.006s  (  0.006s elapsed)
  EXIT    time    0.006s  (  0.006s elapsed)
  Total   time    0.100s  (  0.099s elapsed)

  %GC     time       6.2%  (6.2% elapsed)

  Alloc rate    2,761,447,559 bytes per MUT second

  Productivity  93.8% of total user, 93.8% of total elapsed
```

However the code is simple: ideally there should be no need for vector: optimal code should be possible from just inlining the list generation. Luckily GHC can do this for us[0].

```
module Main (main) where

import System.CPUTime.Rdtsc (rdtsc)
import Text.Printf (printf)
import Data.List (foldl')

data Pair = Pair {-# UNPACK #-}!Int {-# UNPACK #-}!Double

mean' :: [Double] -> Double
mean' xs = v / fromIntegral l
  where
    Pair l v = foldl' f (Pair 0 0) xs
    f (Pair l' v') x = Pair (l' + 1) (v' + x)

main :: IO ()
main = do
  s <- rdtsc
  let r = mean' $ fromIntegral <$> [1 :: Int .. 30000000]
      -- This is slow!
      -- r = mean' [1 .. 30000000]
  e <- seq r rdtsc
  print (e - s, r)
```

This gives us:

```
[nix-shell:/tmp]$ ghc -fforce-recomp -O2 MeanD.hs -o MeanD && ./MeanD +RTS -s
[1 of 1] Compiling Main             ( MeanD.hs, MeanD.o )
Linking MeanD ...
(128434754,1.50000005e7)
         104,064 bytes allocated in the heap
           3,480 bytes copied during GC
          44,384 bytes maximum residency (1 sample(s))
          17,056 bytes maximum slop
               1 MB total memory in use (0 MB lost due to fragmentation)

                                     Tot time (elapsed)  Avg pause  Max pause
  Gen  0         0 colls,     0 par    0.000s   0.000s     0.0000s    0.0000s
  Gen  1         1 colls,     0 par    0.000s   0.000s     0.0000s    0.0000s

  INIT    time    0.000s  (  0.000s elapsed)
  MUT     time    0.032s  (  0.032s elapsed)
  GC      time    0.000s  (  0.000s elapsed)
  EXIT    time    0.000s  (  0.000s elapsed)
  Total   time    0.033s  (  0.032s elapsed)

  %GC     time       0.1%  (0.1% elapsed)

  Alloc rate    3,244,739 bytes per MUT second

  Productivity  99.8% of total user, 99.8% of total elapsed
```

[0]: Notice how I had to map `fromIntegral`: without this, GHC fails to eliminate `[Double]` and the solution is much slower. That is somewhat sad: I don't understand why GHC fails to inline/decides it does not need to without this. If you do have genuine collection of fractionals, then this hack won't work for you and vector may still be necessary.

Comment: Also an interesting note: if we work over `[Int]` and use `-fllvm`, we're able to get pretty much constant-time answer in this case.