# Average value using fold 

Tags: language-agnostic, functional-programming, average

How would I calculate the average of a list of numbers using map and reduce.

Ideally I want to call reduce on a list and get an average back. You may optionally map and filter that list first.

A skeleton LISP attempt:

```
(defun average (list)
  (reduce ... list))
```

A skeleton JS attempt:

```
function average (array) {
  return array.reduce(function() {
    ..
  }, 0);
}
```

If you post an answer with actual code in a language please explain it as if I'm a beginner in that langauge (which I probably will be).

I want to avoid the trivial answer of

```
function average (array) {
   return sum(array) / array.length;
}
```

This uses division at the end rather then a reduce statement. I consider this "cheating".

[[**Edit**]]

Solved my own problem. If anyone has an elegant solution using syntactic sugar from LISP or Haskell I would be interested.

Comment: Better suited for CodeGolf.SE perhaps?

Comment: A simple `reduce` aka `fold` is not `mapreduce` (as in, the Google framework). Not even if you `map` the input beforehand.

Comment: @delnan sorry I got my terminology confused.

Comment: The first step should be working out the maths behind the solution. Can you think about an iterative algorithm that gives you what you want? Turning that into a `fold` shouldn't be too hard.

Comment: @abesto the solution seems so simple now. I wasn't thinking thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a version in common lisp:

```
(defun running-avg (r v)
  (let* ((avg (car r))
         (weight (cdr r))
         (new-weight (1+ weight)))
    (cons (/ (+ (* avg weight) v) new-weight) new-weight)))

(car (reduce 'running-avg '(3 6 5 7 9) :initial-value '(0 . 0)))
;; evaluates to 6
```

It keeps track of a running average and weight, and calculates the new average as the `((previous average * weight) + new value)`.

Comment: could you explain `1+` and `weight`. I know nothing of LISP. Also `* (car r) (cdr r)` Is `r` a tuple?

Comment: `1+` is a function that adds 1 to the argument.  `weight` is just a local variable name.  Yes, `r` is a tuple; I've cleaned it up a bit by creating some meaningful names.

Comment: it's reasonably obvouis what `:initial-value` does but could you explain the semantics of that syntax?

Comment: It's an optional keyword argument to `reduce`.  Common Lisp functions can take named arguments, where the name is a lisp symbol.  The leading colon is just the lisp syntax for symbols.  With an initial value, the first call of the function is with `(initial-value, element0)` instead of `(element0, element1)`.

Comment: Now that I understand the code I prefer the original version because it has that classic LISP terseness :)

Answer (score 3):

As @abesto mentioned it requires an iterative algorithm.

```
Let counter be 0 
For each [value, index] in list   
  let sum be (counter * index) + value   
  let counter be sum / (index + 1)

return counter
```

A javascript implementation would be

```
var average = function(list) { 
    // returns counter
    return list.reduce(function(memo, val, key) {
         // memo is counter
         // memo * key + val is sum. sum / index is counter, counter is returned
         return ((memo * key) + val) / (key + 1)
    // let counter be 0
    }, 0);  
}
```

Answer (score 2):

> calculate the average of a list of numbers using map and reduce

There's no `map` needed. Just a unfold to generate the list, and a fold to reduce it to a mean value:

```
mean n m = uncurry (/) . foldr g (0, 0) . unfoldr f $ n
      where 
        f b | b > m     = Nothing
            | otherwise = Just (b, b+1)

        g x (s,n) = (s+x, n+1)
```

*An efficient implementation*

This structure (`fold . unfold`) allows for the fusion optimization to occur.  A particularly efficient implementation will fuse the unfold (list generation) with the fold (the list reduction). Here, in Haskell, GHC combines the two phases (unfold == `enumFromN`) and the fold via stream fusion:

```
import Data.Vector.Unboxed 

data Pair = Pair !Int !Double

mean :: Vector Double -> Double
mean xs = s / fromIntegral n
  where
    Pair n s       = foldl' k (Pair 0 0) xs
    k (Pair n s) x = Pair (n+1) (s+x)

main = print (mean $ enumFromN 1 (10^7))
```

Which the compiler converts from a composition of two functions, into a recursive loop:

```
main_loop a d e n =
    case ># a 0 of 
      False -> (# I# n, D# e #);
      True -> main_loop (-# a 1) (+## d 1.0) (+## e d) (+# n 1)
```

which reduces to this `goto` in assembly (the C backend to the compiler):

```
Main_mainzuzdszdwfoldlMzqzuloop_info:
        leaq    32(%r12), %rax
        cmpq    %rax, 144(%r13)
        movq    %r12, %rdx
        movq    %rax, %r12
        jb      .L198
        testq   %r14, %r14
        jle     .L202
.L199:
        movapd  %xmm5, %xmm0
        leaq    -1(%r14), %r14
        movsd   .LC0(%rip), %xmm5
        addq    $1, %rsi
        addsd   %xmm0, %xmm6
        movq    %rdx, %r12
        addsd   %xmm0, %xmm5
        jmp     Main_mainzuzdszdwfoldlMzqzuloop_info
```

More efficient, but more confusing implementations result from LLVM (about 2x faster).

---

*References*: [Computing the mean of a list efficiently in Haskell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3300995/computing-the-mean-of-a-list-efficiently-in-haskell)

Answer (score 0):

A description of an apporach in Haskell that allows a compositional approach to folds:
http://conal.net/blog/posts/another-lovely-example-of-type-class-morphisms/

Comment: That article would mean something if I went to the "Haskell for beginners course".

Comment: The linked "beautiful folding" post is somewhat more accessible.

Answer (score 0):

In Mathematica

```
mean[l_List]:=
    Fold[{First@#1+1,(#2 +#1[[2]](First@#1-1))/First@#1}&,{1,1},l][[2]]  

In[23]:= mean[{a,b,c}]
Out[23]= 1/3 (a+b+c)
```