# Stack overflow in monoidal fold over large list

Tags: haskell, stack-overflow, monoids

First some `imports`,

```hs
import Control.Applicative
import Data.Traversable as T
import Data.Foldable as F
import Data.Monoid
```

Say I have a functor holding a pair of values,

```hs
data Fret a = Fret a a deriving (Show)

instance Functor Fret where fmap f (Fret a b) = Fret (f a) (f b)

instance Applicative Fret where
    pure a = Fret a a
    Fret aa ab <*> Fret ba bb = Fret (aa ba) (ab bb)

instance Monoid a => Monoid (Fret a) where
    mempty = Fret mempty mempty
    a `mappend` b = mappend <$> a <*> b
```

I have a large list of these,

```hs
frets = replicate 10000000 (Fret 1 2)
```

over which I want to compute a, e.g., an average,

```hs
data Average a = Average !Int !a deriving (Read, Show)

instance Num a => Monoid (Average a) where
    mempty = Average 0 0
    Average n a `mappend` Average m b = Average (n+m) (a+b)

runAverage :: Fractional a => Average a -> a
runAverage (Average n a) = a / fromIntegral n

average = Average 1
```

Here are a few potential implementations of this,

```hs
average1 = runAverage <$> foldMap (fmap average) frets

average2 = pure (runAverage . mconcat) <*> T.sequenceA (map (pure (Average 1) <*>) frets)
```

Unfortunately, all of these result in a stack overflow.

Thinking that the problem might be excessive laziness in `Foldable.foldMap`, I tried implementing a stricter variant,

```hs
foldMap' :: (F.Foldable f, Monoid m) => (a -> m) -> f a -> m
foldMap' f = F.foldl' (\m a->mappend m $! f a) mempty

average3 = runAverage <$> foldMap' (fmap average) frets
```

Unfortunately, this too overflows.

How can one accomplish this without compromise the clean structure of the approach?

### Update

If I make the fields of `Fret` strict, things appear to work as expected. Checking to see if this works in the larger application.

Comment: That 10M element list is a fairly large CAF to keep around.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Looks like `foldMap` is too lazy, and your `Fret` data type certainly is, leading to a classic `foldl (+)` type space leak, where you accumulate a large chain of thunks trying to reduce your innput list to its average. It is analogous to the [space leaks in list average with tuples](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1618838/laziness-and-tail-recursion-in-haskell-why-is-this-crashing).

Clearly the accumulator in your only loop is too lazy -- the only place you use the stack is in `foldMap`

[image]

Using the same solution - a strict pair type for `Frets` and `foldl'` implementation of `foldMap` is enough, and it will run in constant space:

```
 foldMap' f = F.foldl' (\m -> mappend m . f) mempty
```

and

```
 data Fret a = Fret !a !a
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for another helpful answer! I've noticed that occasionally I run into cases like this where the standard libraries fall short when strictness is necessary. Do you feel that functions like `foldMap'` belong in `Data.Foldable`? 

On one hand functions such as this are quite handy; on the other, it seems like adding every such variant will unreasonably grow the surface area of the standard libraries.

Comment: Folds with accumulators should be strict, I think. You can add laziness with constructors, but it is harder to make them strict after the fact. These pesky operational details don't always get attention in some libraries.