# Summing 1 through 1,000,000 in Haskell gives a stack overflow. What's happening under the hood?

Tags: haskell, sum, stack-overflow

I have the following code.

```
main = print $ sum [1..1000000]
```

When I run I get a stack overflow:

```
Stack space overflow: current size 8388608 bytes.
Use `+RTS -Ksize -RTS' to increase it.
```

I'm accustom to imperative languages like Python which seem to have no problem with such a calculation:

```
sum(range(100000000))  # I'm not even using a generator.
4999999950000000
```

Haskell is obviously different, but I don't quite understand what's happening to cause the stack overflow?  What's going on under the hood to cause the stack overflow in Haskell?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Laziness and tail recursion in Haskell, why is this crashing?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1618838/laziness-and-tail-recursion-in-haskell-why-is-this-crashing)

Comment: I don't think this should be tagged with `python`

Comment: And what happens when you actually use optimization?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

*This entire question is only relevant for GHC<7.10. In recent versions, `sum [1..1000000]` works just fine in constant space, at least on built-in number types*.

---

[`sum` <del>is</del><sup><sub>**used to be**</sub></sup> implemented with the evil `foldl`<sup>1</sup>](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.6.0.1/docs/src/Data-List.html#sum), which isn't as strict as it should be. Thus, what you get from `sum` is essentially a pile of thunks, as large as your input. I think there was a discussion about why it is done this way here at some point... IMO it's basically just stupid, since sums can't normally be consumed lazily anyway it's just obvious to use a [*strict fold*](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.6.0.1/docs/Data-List.html#v:foldl-39-).

> Prelude> :m +Data.List
>   Prelude Data.List> foldl' (+) 0 [1..1000000]
>   500000500000

---

<sup>1</sup>Actually, `foldl` is only used in the report version... but the explicit-recursion version with accumulator is of course no better.

Comment: Is there any reason they haven't fixed this?

Comment: Yeah, strange, isn't it? There's sure [a proposal](https://ghc.haskell.org/trac/haskell-prime/ticket/120), but nobody seems to have been bothering for a few years... perhaps there are some stream-fusion arguments, but I can't really see how that could apply.

Comment: @leftaroundabout Isn't `foldl` notorious for being *bad* at stream fusion, it's not a good consumer. In particular there was recently a discussion on ghc-devs about revamping the frameworking for fusion to make it a good consumer. TLDR `foldl` is just the worst

Comment: So if I remember correctly, the only reason people haven't bothered yet is that the problem goes away when you compile with `-O2` (however, I still think it should be fixed).  Also, jozefg is right and both `foldl`/`foldl'` are bad consumers for stream fusion.  The correct version is `Data.Foldable.foldl'` which should be the official one.

Comment: I suspect the reason it hasn't been changed is that the Haskell Report specifies the lazy behaviour.

Comment: @TomEllis perhaps, but at least all the standard number types can't be evaluated lazily anyway, so there's nothing to be won with `foldl` really. `base-4.8` has thus fixed the issue, so this question is obsolete now.

Answer (score 3):

`sum` is defined in terms of  `foldl` which is lazy in a left associative sort of way so that it has to generate thunks for the whole list before evaluating a single (in this case addition) expression.

You could also define `sum` in terms of `foldl`s stricter counterpart `foldl'` like so:

```
sum' = foldl' (+) 0
```

See [Foldr. Foldl. Foldl'.  from the Haskell Wiki](http://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/Foldr_Foldl_Foldl%27)  for a good explanation of how `foldl` has to generate thunks for every calculation without being able to evaluate anything, which will cause a Stack Overflow.

Comment: Saying `foldl` is lazy is a bit misleading, since unlike `foldr` it always needs to accumulate through the whole list. It basically picks just the bad aspects of non-strict semantics (thunk buildup), without yielding much of the useful properties of lazy code (GC-as-you-go etc.).

Comment: Clarified my answer a bit.